# Matching numbers with regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to match numbers where the first character is either a
- (minus) or NOT a 0 (unless it's the only character in the string) and I'm kinda stuck. `^[-|1-9]?[0-9]+` I've currently got this but it'll match any amount of zeroes.

Examples:

Should match:

```
-16
25
2005
```

Should not match:

```
-05
05
00001
0-017
```

Comment: Hint: The `|` loses it's _special_ meaning inside a character class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a pattern like this:

```
^-?[1-9][0-9]*$
```

This will match optional `-` at the start of the string, followed by a single digit from 1 to 9, followed by zero or more digits from 0 to 9. The start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors ensure that no other characters are allowed before or after the number.

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E-?%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D*$&input=-16%0A25%0A2005%0A%0A-05%0A05%0A00001%0A0-017)

**Update** It has been [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609146/matching-numbers-with-regex/21609183?noredirect=1#comment32648998_21609183) that the above pattern will match any positive or negative decimal integer without leading zeros, but it will not match zero, itself. To handle that case, add an alternation to your pattern like this:

```
^-?[1-9][0-9]*$|^0$
```

Or like this:

```
^(-?[1-9][0-9]*|0)$
```

Comment: Cool, seems to work :) I'll accept your answer as soon as I can. Thanks for the added explanation too, I'm gonna work it through to make sure that I understand it myself.

Comment: As far as I understand OP's first sentence (the part _unless it's the only character in the string_) he wants to match a single `0` too. You could add `|^0$`

Comment: @halex Ahh, thanks for pointing that out. I've included a note about that in my answer.

Comment: @halex Yes, I actually missed that in my examples!